# apply sum function to parse sum of a column from csv into d3.js-chart

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, sum

I have the following dataset in csv format:

```
Month,S40201,S40202,S40203
JAN,79,0,70
FEB,58,26,70
MAR,48,47,46
APR,64,98,77
MAY,79,71,64
JUN,86,103,116
JUL,95,75,95
AUG,0,40,3,5
SEP,60,82,79
OCT,98,101,79
NOV,60,81,75
DEC,7,30,46
```

The D3.js bar chart should display the sum of each column "S40201", "S40202", "S40203" as bar with the corresponding label on the X-axis. Label should be the column name (first row).

```
<script>
// Set the margins
var margin = {top: 60, right: 100, bottom: 20, left: 80},
  width = 850 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 370 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the month variable
var parseMonth = d3.timeParse("%b");
var formatMonth = d3.timeFormat("%b");

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.1)
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);


// Create the svg canvas in the "graph" div
var svg = d3.select("#graph")
        .append("svg")
        .style("width", width + margin.left + margin.right + "px")
        .style("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom + "px")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
        .attr("class", "svg");

// Import the CSV data
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

   // Format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.Month = parseMonth(d.Month);
      d.S40201 = +d.S40201;
      d.S40202 = +d.S40202;
      d.S40203 = +d.S40203;
  });

    var nest = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d){
        return d.S40201,d.S40202,d.S40203;
      })
      .sortKeys(d3.ascending)
      .rollup(function(leaves){
            return d3.sum(leaves, function(d) {return (d.S40201,d.S40203,d.S40203)});
        })
      .entries(data)

console.log(nest)
  // Scale the range of the data
  x.domain(nest.map(function(d) { return d.key; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(nest, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

  // Set up the x axis
  var xaxis = svg.append("g")
       .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
       .attr("class", "x axis")
       .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
          //.ticks(d3.timeMonth)
          .tickSize(0, 0)
          //.tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%B"))
          .tickSizeInner(0)
          .tickPadding(10));

  // Add the Y Axis
   var yaxis = svg.append("g")
       .attr("class", "y axis")
       .call(d3.axisLeft(y)
          .ticks(5)
          .tickSizeInner(0)
          .tickPadding(6)
          .tickSize(0, 0));

 // yaxis.select(".domain").style("display","none")

  // Add a label to the y axis
  svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 0 - 60)
        .attr("x", 0 - (height / 2))
        .attr("dy", "1em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Annual Sales")
        .attr("class", "y axis label");

  // Draw the bars
  svg.selectAll(".rect")
      .data(nest)
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
          .attr("class", "bar")
          .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.key); })
          .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
          .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
          .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });



})
</script>
```

With just one column it works fine, but If I want to add more than one column it doesn´t work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow. The problem you face is your nested data is not the way you like. If you console log your nested data the way you have it, the key and the value are both the same and not the headers.

Instead if you manually summarize the data the way you like it would be easier. For example:

```
var nest = [];//create empty array
var keys = Object.keys(data[0]); //get the headers for your data
//for each header push the sum as an object
keys.forEach(function (d, i) {
  if (i == 0) return;//ignore first column as that is month
  //get the sumfrom your data for all the values of this key i.e. d
  var sum = d3.sum (data, function(e){ return e[d] }); 
  //create an object with this key value pair
  var obj = {
    key: d, //column name
    value: sum //sum for the column
  }
  nest.push(obj); //push this as an object in the nest array
})
```

Here is a block with the correct code showing the headers as the labels on the x-axis and the sum values.
https://bl.ocks.org/akulmehta/724d63f0108304ede84a14fc145aad28

Please feel free to comment if you need more explanation /guidance and please remember to mark it as an answer if this answers your question.

**Update 1- For selected columns only**

Based on the comments below, if you want selected columns only simply replace the `var keys = Object.keys(data[0]);` with an array of headers like `var keys = ['S40201','S40202','S40203']` and also remove the line `if (i == 0) return;//ignore first column as that is month` as we do not have the month's column anymore. Final code for this part should look like this:

```
var nest = [];//create empty array
var keys = ['S40201','S40202','S40203']; //the headers for your data
//for each header push the sum as an object
keys.forEach(function (d, i) {
  //get the sumfrom your data for all the values of this key i.e. d
  var sum = d3.sum (data, function(e){ return e[d] }); 
  //create an object with this key value pair
  var obj = {
    key: d, //column name
    value: sum //sum for the column
  }
  nest.push(obj); //push this as an object in the nest array
})
```

And here is the block to demonstrate it works. Notice the CSV file has an additional column but it the graph ignores this. https://bl.ocks.org/akulmehta/724d63f0108304ede84a14fc145aad28

Comment: Thank you very much, that works fine. But I have more columns (not only S40201,S40202,S40203). I have some more columns "S40501", "S40502", "S40503" in my dataset but I only want to parse those specified in the code and not all columns in the dataset.    // Format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.Month = parseMonth(d.Month);
      d.S40201 = +d.S40201;
      d.S40202 = +d.S40202;
      d.S40203 = +d.S40203;

Comment: Hi rob, I have updated my answer for your specific use case. See the Update 1 above. Please feel free to comment if you need more explanation /guidance and please remember to mark it as an answer if this answers your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers